# Combining multiple images, in many folders in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy-ndarray

I have a folder of grayscale images (100x100 pixels) with files names as such:

- file_123_A.ome.tif
- file_123_B.ome.tif
- file_123_C.ome.tif
- file_125_A.ome.tif
- file_125_B.ome.tif
- file_125_C.ome.tif

The number of each file name (123 and 125 in my above examples) links the images, so those set of images are related.

I am trying to read in the files into a numpy array and then combine the three related images into a new image of either 100x100x3 or 100x300.

I can happily read the images from the A set into one array and then the images from the B and C sets into their own individual arrays. However once I have done this I can not longer check the filenames and that the images are in the same order so if image 0 in the A array is the correct related image in the B and C arrays. I can do this and have got it working successfully, but I am not sure it is the best solution.

Since the number for each image is unique I want to code out a solution that reads in the filenames and checks that the three images have the same unique number and are a set e.g. A,B,C images then combines them accordingly. This I am struggling with if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Not sure how well I have explained this so if you need clarification please ask.

Thanks

Update:

This code (see below) gets me a set of unique file names within a directory and subdirectory. It might not be the most efficient but it works. What I am struggling with now is now to use this loop over the actual image files make a comparison and merge or join the three images with each unique ID.

```
#Set directory to look in
file = glob.glob(r'my_directory\**\*.tif',recursive = True)

#Loop though the files and put all the uniques files name into a list
fname_lst = []
for img in file:
    i = img.split('\\')[5][:-12]
    fname_lst.append(i)
fname_lst = set(fname_lst)
```

Obviously the .split is unique to my file names but it does work.

Comment: Do you mean your script should recurse down through a whole bunch of directories joining images, or that it should do all the images in a single directory or that you should pass it the parameter `file_XXX` and it should just join the images in the current directory that start with that prefix? I guess I am asking what parameter(s) do you want to call the script with?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to find all the images in a folder that have the same XXX, and join the A,B,C versions of those images together. Doing it for subdirectories might get complex as the file from file_XXX changes in each sub directory. Does that make sense?

Comment: Try using `glob()` to get a list of all the TIFFs. Then remove everything in each filename after the second underscore and add the result to a set - then you will have a set of the unique filename prefixes. You can then iterate over these, adding the `A/B/C` suffix and merge the files.

Comment: I think I understand your approach. I will have a go thanks for the response.

Comment: Have a try. Click `edit` under your question and paste in any code you get working and say where you are stuck.

Comment: Try splitting your problem up into simpler pieces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want to all groups of files in the current directory. I'll leave you to add error handling and other little variations:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
from glob import glob

# Get list of files matching "*A.ome.tif"
files = glob("*A.ome.tif")

# Get list of unique stems
stems = [f.replace('A.ome.tif', '') for f in files]

# Iterate over unique stems
for stem in stems:
    A = cv2.imread(stem + 'A.ome.tif')
    B = cv2.imread(stem + 'B.ome.tif')
    C = cv2.imread(stem + 'C.ome.tif')
    # Stack images horizontally (side-by-side), use np.dstack() for merging channels
    result = np.hstack((A,B,C))
    cv2.imwrite(stem + 'result.tif', result)
```

Comment: That is brilliant thank you very much Mark, with a little editing for specific directories, I have it working. What is better is that I can actually look at this and see what it is doing mainly. There are a couple of bits that I will need to check out and read up on.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project. Come back and ask a new question if you get stuck - questions (and answers) are free :-)